# Remove first value in multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The following code looks at a grid layout of elements and is designed to track the height of each element.

```
let columns = document.getElementsByClassName('_3Rcdf');

let cellHeights = new Array(columns);
for (let j=0; j<columns.length; j++) {
    for (let i=0; i<columns[j].children.length; i++) {
        cellHeights[j] = new Array(columns[j].children[i].length); 
    }  
}
for (let k=0; k<cellHeights.length; k++) {
    for (let i=0; i<columns[k].children.length; i++) {
        cellHeights[k].push(columns[k].children[i].clientHeight);           
    } 
}
```

Ideally what `console.log(cellHeights)` should return is:
The expected output would be

```
cellHeights = [
    [333, 372, 333],
    [333, 333],
    [372, 352]
]
```

But what my code actually returns is:

```
cellHeights = [
    [undefined, 333, 372, 333],
    [undefined, 333, 333],
    [undefined, 372, 352]
]
```

I have figured out the problem is in this line:
`cellHeights[j] = new Array(columns[j].children[i].length);` 
What this is doing is creating 3 arrays inside the `cellHeights` array which are empty, thus the undefined. I think I need to immediately populate the arrays as they are created but I am not sure how to do so. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't initialize the array with a length.

`push`ing into an array like that just adds them at the end of the array, even if the entries aren't actually filled with values:

```js
const newArr = new Array(1);

console.log(newArr);

newArr.push(42);

console.log(newArr);
```

Instead of:

```
cellHeights[j] = new Array(columns[j].children[i].length);
```

Just assign an empty array:

```
cellHeights[j] = [];
```

Comment: That was a surprisingly easy fix. Thank you so much :)